# How to export Google Cloud Computer Instance Image?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

How to export google compute engine instance image ?. I want to reuse the instance in another google cloud account. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

[Here's](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/export-image) the documentation for exporting an image, and [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/import-existing-image) for importing an image.

Comment: thanks.I have one doubt how to use same external IP in another account.Is that possible?Or i need to update dns.

Comment: I think that you can't move external IP between accounts.

Answer (score 0):

You can also share images across projects by granting the “[compute.imageUser](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/iam#image_user_role)” IAM role. As explained in [this article](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/sharing-images-across-projects):

“For example, assume that a User A owns Project A and wants to create VM instances using images owned by Project B. The owner of Project B must grant User A the [compute.imageUser](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/iam#image_user_role) role on Project B. This grants User A the ability to use the images from Project B to create instances in Project A.”

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible.

First of all, `Instance` and `Image` are two different things. Image is more like an install-able package and Instance is the actual installed version.

What might be confusing here, w.r.t. Google Cloud is that Google refers to creating an instance from image as `Exporting an Image` which is contrary to `VMWare` or other hypervisor based virtualization terminology where creating an instance is done by `Importing a VM (template)` and `Exporting a VM` is basically reverse of installation i.e. creating a re-loadable package from installed version of VM.

This process of creating an Image from VM Instance is called `Creating an Image` in Google Cloud and the process for same is documented [**here**](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/create-delete-deprecate-private-images#creating_a_custom_image)